# SELECT rows where col1 is value and another row where col1 is not value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my database which has the columns:

- callid
- event

i am running this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT callid) as r FROM voipnow.ast_queue_log 
WHERE queuename = '0536*401' 
AND time > '2014-03-19 15:38:00' 
AND callid NOT IN (SELECT callid FROM voipnow.ast_queue_log 
                   WHERE event = 'CONNECT' 
                   OR event = 'ABANDON') 
AND event = 'RINGNOANSWER'
```

which shows all rows where the CALLID column is the same but where there is no row that has the event `CONNECT` or `ABANDON` or `RINGNOANSWER`

so when the caller is waiting there are only ever rows with events `ENTERQUEUE` or `RINGNOANSWER`

this is working fine, however when the first row is inserted (with event `ENTERQUEUE`) it should be displaying a count of 1 but it shows 0 until another row is inserted with event `RINGNOANSWER`

Comment: Now that I've fixed your indentation, do you see why it's working that way? Maybe you should put `OR event = 'RINGNOANSWER'` in the subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT callid) as r 
FROM voipnow.ast_queue_log 
WHERE queuename = '0536*401' 
AND time > '2014-03-19 15:38:00' 
AND callid NOT IN (SELECT callid FROM voipnow.ast_queue_log 
                   WHERE event IN ('CONNECT', 'ABANDON', 'RINGNOANSWER'))
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b98af/1)

Comment: when there is a row with only ENTERQUEUE is still displays 0

Comment: It displays 1 for me, see the sqlfiddle demo.